# remove directory url for framework with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

i have this code .htaccess
work for laravel framework

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

which work fine but 
the problem in framework 
i go to site example.com/testing

the problem **laravel** framework read /testing as route

so i have put all route under testing

so the Question is :how can i make apache send PHP route without "/testing"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply excluding from the scope all requests that match /testing path. View [htaccess docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testing$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

But anyway you **should not do this**, you are redirecting your incoming requests to `/testing/public/index.php`.

You have to configure the virtualhost pointing directly to `/public` folder in your laravel application as described in http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

And this is **why you should do**: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56736/is-web-app-safe-in-not-public-folder